# Send different HTTP headers depending on conditions

Tags: http-headers, jmeter

I am using JMeter to test an HTTP server that accepts and validates an APIKey and returns a time limited token on success.  I want to send a token if I have one and an APIKey if I don't so I have complementary If controllers each of which have HTTP Header Managers beneath them.

Neither HTTP Header manager is actioned.

By adding other components alongside the HTTP Header managers I can see that these are conditionally executed but the HTTP Header Managers are still ignored.  If I copy an HTTP Header Manager up out of the If controller (to the same level as the HTTP Request) then is is acted upon.

Is this usage supposed to work?  If not, is there a way to conditionally set HTTP headers that does work?

[image]

Comment: yes it is supposes to work, could you show a screenshot of test plan and check jmeter.log file for errors ?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the post.  There are no errors in the log file which has been set to DEBUG level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

- move the sampler inside each IfController
- and move  listeners outside of Thread Group (not related to issue)

Comment: That works very well thank you.  I thought the listeners had to be children of the request but it seems not.

Comment: So duplicate the http sampler? Would be ideal if that was not necessary